# Keyup Event Not Work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, 19.04

The problem has come for a long time for me.

The keyup events for key A-Z do not work in `<input type="text">` in the latest version of Google Chrome (Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

Only keys like `ESC`, `Enter`, `Delete` ... etc work.

Does anyone have the same problem?

**Works**: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event

**Doesn't work**: 
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_keydown_keyup

Comment: I ***does*** work in my configuration. Ubuntu 19.04, Chrome Version 77.0.3865.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Also works in Kubuntu 18.04, Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit). Do you use a bluetooth keyboard?

Comment: @danzel I use normal wired keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the reason why keyup does not work. It was because the English input of the Chinese input method "Chewing" is lightly different from native English input method.

Take typing a character "A" for example:

**Native English Input Method**

1. keydown
2. keypress
3. "A"
4. keyup

**Chinese Chewing Input Method**

1. keydown
2. "A"

Both of keypress and keydown event were not triggered.